# Qchainage: python error with QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis, point, qgis-3, qchainage

I get a following python error while working with QChainage-tool in QGIS 3.2. Because of that (assumably) the OK-button is also greyed out. My goal is to retrieve start and end points of line features.

[image: Python error:...SetSourceCrs():not enough arguments]

[image: Qchainage dialog]

Is there anyone capable of telling me whether this a result of plugin being still experimental in QGIS 3?

Comment: The [plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qchainage/) seems to have been last updated over a year ago so it may still require fine-tuning for it to work properly for QGIS 3.

Comment: I wonder if github author of the plugin, _macho_, could comment on this? I don't know if he/she is active on this site.